# Union SQL Injection

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-injection

I'm trying to demo SQL Injection with a `UNION` query but I'm not getting results.

This is the C# code and the database is SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cString);
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "select * from Users where UserName='" + userName 
                   + "' and Password='" + password + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(" " + reader.GetName(i));
                sb.Append(": ");
                sb.Append(reader[i]);
            }
            sb.Append("<br />");
        }
        dataLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
```

I have a username and password text boxes and the input is passed to this method. 

I tried the following but no result:

```
'UNION SELECT * FROM products --
```

the `Users` table and `Products` table have identical column types (`int, nvarchar, nvarchar`).

Can someone help? What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? You receive no resultset, wrong resultset, error message or what?

Comment: Do you have records in your tables?

Comment: @Quassnoi I am only getting result from the Products table and nothing from the Users table. And yes I have records in both tables. I was hoping to get a combined result from both tables.

Comment: Do the username and password have a matching row in the Users table?

Comment: You can't put a union in the where clause then expect results from both tables.  The best way to demo this would be to do something like ' delete from products.

Comment: @tsells not sure what you mean. For this query, which table won't yield results? `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE foo=1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Every single programmer tries to prevent SQL injection, but you've decided you like it so you violate all the programming principles? Can't see a point in your endeavour...

Comment: the classical way to do it is to use `' or 1=1 UNION SELECT * FROM products --`

Comment: @walther - if you read the OP's question - he is trying to demo it - my guess would be to his team to show what could happen if they don't prevent it.

Comment: @tsells, there are sites that provide the exact same functionality.. This one for instance: http://sqlzoo.net/hack/ .. It's a waste of time trying to produce the same result on your own, cause as I've already said, it doesn't provide any learning value and violates pretty much every rule you should follow. By the way, I'm not convinced, that your scenario is "the one", because would you have a team if you couldn't demo such a trivial task as this? I would immediately resign on the leader programmer post if it were me and this was the case..

Comment: @walther, I would believe nothing is a waste of time if you learn something from it.  Who are you (or anyone else for that matter) to decide what does and what does not provide learning value to someone?  I think that philosophy is very close minded - and hopefully you can move past it some day.  Everything we do provides experience that we can draw upon to make better decisions in the future.  This applies to programming as well as most things in life.

Comment: @tsells, yup, so you roam around occasionally jumping down the cliffs, because others might be wrong about the gravity, right? Some things are worthy for exploration and experimentation, some are not. SQL injection has been proven way too many times for my taste and this, sir, is an utter waste of time. If you can see a value in this "experiment", well, it's your time. Mine is too valuable for such nonsense. I prefer to learn how to prevent these injections, not how to cause their possibility...

Comment: @walther And that is your preference - go do it.  But please don't bash people on here that want to make the choice to learn more about their craft - in whatever ways they choose.  If you don't agree move on - but please add something productive to the conversation.  May you have a blessed day....I'm out.

Comment: @tsells, I don't bash anyone, I just asked a simple question. Still no answer. In my opinion it's productive to ask questions, that may help people to see their struggle from a different angle. If you don't agree, move on, you're not the OP, nor in any way involved in this topic. The only person bashing someone else for his opinions is actually you, telling me what I can or can't ask. Every single answer here contains the same thing I've expressed, so it seems I'm not the only one here with the same thoughts on this matter... Have a nice day as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing `' UNION SELECT * FROM Products` into the `password` parameter, then your query looks like this (assuming you put `foo` or any other valid or invalid username into `username`):

```sql
SELECT * from Users 
  where UserName='foo' and Password='' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Products --'
```

Unless you have a row in `Users` that matches that where clause (even if you use a valid username, which a malicious user might only be able to guess, there is still a blank password which certainly won't match), why do you expect any rows to come back from the `Users` table?

And if you are passing this value into username, you end up with this:

```sql
SELECT * from Users 
  where UserName='' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Products -- and Password='foo'
```

Again, unless you have a username with a blank username, why would you expect any rows?

Anyway, there are lots of great materials out there describing SQL injection. Why do you want to re-invent the wheel? Why not just enforce parameterized queries, and let them read the existing materials for the details on why? Here are just a few great resources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2011/02/16/sql-server-sql-injection-from-start-to-end.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I do agree with Aaron: Use the resources out there instead of reinventing the wheel. However I do also understand that showing how vulnerable your own application is can be very powerful. So to make your query work, you need to pass the following into UserName and Password:

`' OR 1=1;--`

That works independent of the order of Password and UserName in the query. It will return all user's records. You don't neet to add the product table in there.